# Exclude method signature using autodoc

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm currently documenting a HTTP API using the Sphinx `httpdomain` extension. I have a docstring on each request endpoint that documents the argument, query params, return value and exceptions. I would like for this docstring to be used in a Sphinx document.

Currently I used the automethod directive like:

```
.. automethod:: Controller.method
```

This will format the docstring including the correct formatting using the `httpdomain`, however, it also print the method signature (as it always does.) The result looks somewhat like:

```
Controller.method()
GET /endpoint_url
Docstring describing the resource.
```

I basically want it to skip the first line. I found another question on SO similar to this, with a solution to suppress all method signatures. However, this documentation is part of a larger project, and I would like to keep `autodoc` functionality as-is for all other autogenerated documentation.

Comment: You mean manually? Then I'd have to maintain documentation in two different files, which is exactly what I'm trying to prevent.

Comment: Maintaining both the py and the rst file is not the problem, the problem is maintaining duplicate content. Also, it's not one method, it concerns roughly 100 methods.